# OpenThread Border Router with serial NCP

Tags: openthread

The [Border Router setup guide](https://openthread.io/guides/border_router/build#set-up-the-border-router) spells out how to connect a USB-based network coprocessor. As I understand it, it is easy to use a serial connection of the host to connect to an NCP. Is it just a matter of changing the configuration of [`wpantund`](https://github.com/openthread/wpantund/blob/master/src/wpantund/wpantund.conf#L16)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configurating wpantund for serial communication is all done through the `Config:NCP:SocketPath` option.  The NCP connection in the USB-based example is presented as a standard linux tty device.  If your specific NCP configuration also presents the connection as a tty device, then you likely just need to change the `/dev/tty*` path.

If you are planning to use an SPI connection, take a look at [spi-hdlc-adapter](https://github.com/openthread/openthread/tree/master/tools/spi-hdlc-adapter), which allows using the SPI connection as if it were a serial stream.

Comment: I noticed that the README for spi-hdlc-adapter mentions linuxy things like sysfs. Is it a portable library that can be used with non-linux hosts like FreeRTOS?

Comment: Unfortunately, spi-hdlc-adapter is not currently structured as a portable library for non-linux hosts.